# race-free directory walk (C++)

Tags: c++, linux, filesystems, race-condition, stat

I need to walk a directory tree and get stat values for every file.  I want to do this safely while the filesystem is being modified.

In Python, the best option is [`os.fwalk`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/os.html#os.fwalk), which gives access to the fd for the directory being traversed; I can then `os.stat` with the dir_fd (`fstatat`) and get current stat values.  This is as race-free as it can be made on Linux (if the contents of this directory are being modified, I may have to rescan it).  In C, there is [`nftw`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html), which is implemented similarly, and [`fts`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fts.3.html), which in glibc uses a plain (l)stat and therefore is racy (it reduces the race window by changing directories, which is inconvenient).

C++ has a new [filesystem API](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs) [graduated from boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/filesystem/doc/), which caches `stat` values but [doesn't expose them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23540985/how-to-get-the-inode-with-boostfilesystem) (and I need access to st_dev).  This isn't purely a header library, so I can't work around that.

Am I missing a decent C++ option, that uses `fstatat` and isn't bound by Boost's ideal of not exposing platform-specific calls?  Or is my best option to wrap `nftw` (or even `find`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was simple enough to implement.

I used [libposix](https://github.com/dryproject/libposix/) from dryproject.

```
#include <posix++.h>

class Walker {
public:
    void walk(posix::directory dir) {
        dir.for_each([this, dir](auto& dirent) {
            if (dirent.name == "." or dirent.name == "..")
                    return;
            if (!handle_dirent(dirent))
                return;
            struct stat stat;
            if (dirent.type == DT_DIR || dirent.type == DT_UNKNOWN) {
                int fd = openat(
                    dir.fd(), dirent.name.c_str(), O_DIRECTORY|O_NOFOLLOW|O_NOATIME);
                if (fd < 0) {
                    // ELOOP when O_NOFOLLOW is used on a symlink
                    if (errno == ENOTDIR || errno == ELOOP)
                        goto enotdir;
                    if (errno == ENOENT)
                        goto enoent;
                    posix::throw_error(
                        "openat", "%d, \"%s\"", dir.fd(), dirent.name);
                }
                posix::directory dir1(fd);
                fstat(fd, &stat);
                if (handle_directory(dirent, fd, stat))
                    walk(dir1);
                close(fd);
                return;
            }
enotdir:
            try {
                dir.stat(dirent.name.c_str(), stat, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW);
            } catch (const posix::runtime_error &error) {
                if (error.number() == ENOENT)
                    goto enoent;
                throw;
            }
            handle_file(dirent, stat);
            return;
enoent:
            handle_missing(dirent);
        });
    }
protected:
    /* return value: whether to stat */
    virtual bool handle_dirent(const posix::directory::entry&) { return true; }
    /* return value: whether to recurse
     * stat will refer to a directory, dirent info may be obsolete */
    virtual bool handle_directory(
            const posix::directory::entry &dirent,
            const int fd, const struct stat&) { return true; }
    /* stat might refer to a directory in case of a race;
     * it still won't be recursed into.  dirent may be obsolete. */
    virtual void handle_file(
            const posix::directory::entry &dirent,
            const struct stat&) {}
    /* in case of a race */
    virtual void handle_missing(
            const posix::directory::entry &dirent) {}
};
```

Performance is identical to GNU find (when comparing with the base class, using `-size $RANDOM` to suppress output and force `find` to `stat` all files, not just `DT_DIR` candidates).